# unresolved external symbol "class Fl_Graphics_Driver * fl_graphics_driver"

Tags: graphics, visual-studio-2017, fltk

I am trying to implement a cpp project in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 with FLTK and face the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class Fl_Graphics_Driver * fl_graphics_driver" (?fl_graphics_driver@@3PAVFl_Graphics_Driver@@A) Project 1   C:\Users\username\somefolder\Project1-Skeleton\ImageWidget.obj  1

Comment: looks like you did not link the FLTK to your project ... it is DLL/OBJ or has Cpp ? your project has the header file included but not the code itself ...

Comment: I changed the 'fltkdlld.lib' to 'fltkd.lib'. It works now.